# Searching possibilities travelling by ship from India to South East Asia

Tags: bicycles, freighter-travel

My wife and I are travelling by bicycle from the Netherlands to South East Asia. At the moment we are in Georgia, Tbilisi and in 4 months we will reach by land (Armenia, Iran, Pakistan) somewhere in India. Because we cannot fly and the border India-Myanmar is closest we are trying to find opportunities for an itinerary by ship from India to Thailand, Myanmar etc..
Does anyone have experience with this or any idea how to find a cargo or private ship?

See here the questions we already sent to some cargo companies.

We are searching for an itinerary:

1. A ship that is going from India, Mumbai, Calcutta or Madras (Chennai) leaving around the middle of December 2022:

- to Yangon, Myanmar or
- to Bangkok, Thailand or
- to a Harbourcity in Cambodia or
- to a Harbourcity in Vietnam

2. A ship going from Muscat, Oman or from Dubai or Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates or from Bandar Abbas, Iran leaving around beginning or middle of November 2022:

- to Yangon, Myanmar or
- to Bangkok, Thailand or
- to a Harbourcity in Cambodia or
- to a Harbourcity in Vietnam

3. A ship that is going from the Andaman Islands, India to a harbourcity in Myanmar or Thailand leaving around end of December 2022.

Comment: I suppose you have found the passage by freighter specialists websites? Some say that such passages have been suspended due to Covid, that might have changed.

Comment: I presume you mean South East *Asia* in your first sentence?